# Reusable Content List not showing in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, reusability

I'm trying to get the Reusable Content List on my SharePoint site, for that i have activated the office sharepoint server publishing infrastructure feature, even when that feature is active the Reusable Content List is not being displayed.  Does anyone knows what could be the reason of this?

Thanks in Advance, i really appreciate the help

Comment: I've got the same problem. Publishing features are activated on both Site and Web scopes. Reusable Content List is still missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try activating the other publishing features, as well. The infrastructure feature is at the site collection level, but the "Office SharePoint Server Publishing" feature is at the site level. If that doesn't cut it, also ensure the "Office SharePoint Server Standard Site features feature" is enabled

Answer (score 0):

Reusable Content shows up in the top level site collection.
Go to Site Setting>Go to top level Site collection > View all site contents > Reusable List.